# Custom Field get wrong display name on custom lists

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, sharepoint-fields

I've declaratively created around a total of 50 custom fields. They are included in a content type.

The problem is when i create a custom list that uses the content type the fields get a missmatch of the displayname value.

As an example, I have a field with the following:

> **On Site Column Level and in the Content type:**
>
> - InternalName: a
> - Guid: 123
> - DisplayName: b
>
> **On Custom List:**
>
> - InternalName: a
> - Guid: 123
> - DisplayName: c
>
> ***What I want on my Custom List:***
>
> - *InternalName: a*
> - *Guid: 123*
> - *DisplayName: b*

So to be clear. The problem is on lists when I've added the content type.

I've crosschecked every step that I've done (The the guids, dispName, internalNames are correct in the content types xml.)

Don't have the same issue on the same server when i try with another custom Content Type.

However when I add the custom fields directly on the Custom List I don't get the same results. "It Works"

I've tested with adding manually and through `ContentTypeRef` in my List Definitions Schema

Comment: How are you adding the field to the list? Do you happen to give it another display name in for example a list definition?

Comment: First Q: I've tested with adding manually and through ContentTypeRef in my List Definitions Schema. Second Q: I'm not givning two values. There should not be a differens between them. (It should be "b" in both instances)

Comment: OK, if it is the same behaviour when you add the field manually to the list, there should be no issue with the `FieldRef` in the list schema

Comment: However that doesn't solve my problem. By using either of the mentioned method i still get the faulty behavior.

Comment: You say this: "However when I add the custom fields directly on the Custom List I don't get the same results. "It Works"", but then you say that the behaviour is the same, you lost me

Comment: Sorry about that. When I manually add fields to the custom list without management of content types turned on. The fields are correct. But When I Add the fields By adding the Content Type, thats when the problem is.

Comment: Can you see if the field has correct name in List Settings, or is it just in a view it is incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25483/discussion-between-george-norberg-and-robert-lindgren).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to an automated Visual studio function when adding the Content Type to the List Definition using Visual Studios Interface. Somehow a mismatch was created.

Although recreating the list definition solved my issue it doesn't explain why there was a problem when I add the Content Type to Manually created Custom lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Inherits='TRUE'` then you may be getting the expected behavior. In this case changes to any of the properties of fields inherited from the base type will be ignored. Also, any attempts to remove fields inherited from the base type will be ignored. As far as I can tell, the only thing you can do when Inherits is true is add additional fields to the type – everything else is ignored.

See [Custom Content Types and Inherits in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2011/05/01/custom-content-types-and-inherits-in-sharepoint-2010/) for more detail.